# how to close already opened popup

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap popup. and I am using the following code in jsp.

**JSP:-**
JSP dependency is

`<script src="js/commons/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.js"></script>`

```
</style>   
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">{{ctrl.modalHeader}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            {{ctrl.modalBody}}

        <ul ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list">
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{value}}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
            <!--<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()"><spring:message code="label.close"/></button>-->
        </div>
    </script>
```

The following code added in Jscontroller.For Opening and closing the function.

**jsController:-**

```
$scope.open = function() {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: function($uibModalInstance) {

                var self = this;
                self.modalHeader = modalHeader;
                self.modalBody = modalBody;
                self.list = exceptions;

                self.ok = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                };

                self.cancel = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        });
    }
```

I will call the function like the below.

```
$scope.open();
```

Finally I want to find whether the Popup is already opened or not. If already Opened I want to close the existing popup and I want to open new popup. Already I am opening the popup with  `$scope.open();`. And I want to Find how to close the popup.

How to close the existing opened popup.

Answer (score 0):

You check the class name of the element which you have popping. If the pop up is already opened means the new class will be added to the element of popup (element). So you can check by checking whther the class is added or not to the element.

Answer (score 0):

($("element").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown

When the modal is not yet opened, .data('bs.modal') returns undefined, hence the || {} - which will make isShown the (falsy) value undefined. If you're into strictness one could do ($("element").data('bs.modal') || {isShown: false}).isShown

Answer (score 0):

```
app.service('ModalService', function($uibModal) {
var isOpen = false,

this.isOpenPopup = function () {
   return isOpen;
};

this.open = function() {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: function($uibModalInstance) {

            var self = this;
            self.modalHeader = modalHeader;
            self.modalBody = modalBody;
            self.list = exceptions;

            self.ok = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
                // set isOpen false for close popup 
                isOpen=false;
            };

            self.cancel = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                // set isOpen false for close popup 
                isOpen=false;

            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    });

    //set isOpen flag here
    isOpen=true;
}
```

};

Comment: can you please explain a bit

Comment: add a one service inside it set isOpen flag while calling service.open() function. same do for close popup.

Comment: I want to find how to close the popup. I can find whether the popup is opened or not now. I want to know Closing the popup code

Comment: assigned it while open popup 
like this $rootScope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
and 
close using as $rootScope.modalInstance.close('a');

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you in popups

```
$(".modal").modal("hide");  // close the active popup

$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    // the function trigger when the popup is closed
}
```

Comment: can you please help litle more

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?